# Как выбрать материалы по связующей таблице?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Есть таблицы `Materials` и `Tags`, связанные как `Многие-ко-многим` через дополнительную таблицу `Material_Tag`. Необходимо при получении материалов `Material::get();` поставить условие соответствия переданному списку тегов. Если данные находятся в одной таблице, то это делается посредством `Material::where(...)->get();`. Как быть, если данные находятся в разных таблицах и связаны через `belongsToMany()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас связь `belongsToMany` для тегов и Вам нужно получить метериалы в зависимости от тегов:

```
Material::whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
    // нужные условия
    $query->where('field', 'field name');
})->get();
```